# MySQL field from UNION SUBSELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union, subquery

My database has the following tables:

- t1: blog posts
- t2: additional table for each blog post
- t3: english comments for blog posts
- t4: spanish comments for blog posts

And I have the following use case:
I need to fetch the id of the newest comment per blog post together with the blog post itself. The newest comment might be either in the t3 or t4 table.

I came up with the following sql, but it does not work as expected.

```
SELECT t1.id,
t1.one, 
t1.two, 
(
    SELECT id FROM (
        (SELECT * FROM t3 where t3.refid = t1.id) 
        UNION (SELECT * FROM t4 where t4.refid = t1.id) 
        ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS tempTable) 
AS someValue
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) 
WHERE t1.otherid=42 AND t1.somefield > 0 
ORDER BY t1.someOtherField 
LIMIT 5
```

Any hints on if and/or how this is possible are highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When you say it does not work as expected, what is currently happening?  Also tables t3 and t4 do they have unique primary keys, as in how are you going to dectect if you are going to show an English comment instead of a Spanish comment let's say?

Comment: sorry, i should have written that in the post. mysql says "Unknown column t1.id", it seems that the subselect has no access on data from the outer query. this is probably because the subselect is in the select_expr, not in the where_condition.

Comment: i want to show the comment from the table which holds the newest comment. and of course there are keys in the real tables - these are just dummy ones.. ;)

Comment: I see.  One possibility would be you encapsulate the t3/t4 union in a view providing a way to access all comments in one, and therfore the subselect should then work.  This has the added bonus of any other code that refers to comments can use the view without repeating the union logic.  I suppose I'm tempted to ask why are comments not in a single table with a language attribue denoting English or Spanish?

Comment: thanks, i'll see how far i get using a view. But i think that what i want should be possible using only a single query without a view, since from my understanding this is what a relational db is ment to be used for.

to answer your questions: historical reasons, the different tables are a cheap way of partitioning data at the time the tables where created, and currently i have to work using this scheme :/

Comment: just found out that mysql does not have materialized views. my t3/t4 tables have ~100.000.000 entries, so sadly your suggestion does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to compile a table with the most recent comments from t3 and t4 into table `d`
then also combine the two results into comments table `c`
this `c` would hold only 1 entry, the most recent id, either from `t3`, or from `t4`

`c.t` will tell you from which table you got the response;

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.*, 
       c.id AS cid, 
       c.dt AS dt, 
       c.t  AS t 
FROM   t1 
       LEFT JOIN t2 
         ON ( t1.id = t2.id ) 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.id, 
                         Max(d.dt) AS dt, 
                         d.refid, 
                         d.t       AS t 
                  FROM   (SELECT t3.id, 
                                 Max(DATETIME) AS dt, 
                                 t3.refid, 
                                 3             AS t 
                          FROM   t3 
                          GROUP  BY t3.refid 
                          UNION ALL 
                          SELECT t4.id, 
                                 Max(DATETIME) AS dt, 
                                 t4.refid, 
                                 4             AS t 
                          FROM   t4 
                          GROUP  BY t4.refid) d 
                  GROUP  BY d.refid) c 
         ON c.refid = t1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query firstly, it should return the latest comments from t3 and t4 -

```
SELECT t_comments1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM t3 UNION SELECT * FROM t4) t_comments1
  JOIN (SELECT refid, MAX(datetime) max_datetime FROM (SELECT * FROM t3 UNION SELECT * FROM t4) t GROUP BY t.refid) t_comments2
    ON t_comments1.refid = t_comments2.refid AND t_comments1.datetime = t_comments2.max_datetime;
```

If it OK, then let us combine this query with a t1 table -

```
SELECT t1.*, t_comments.* FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t_comments1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM t3 UNION SELECT * FROM t4) t_comments1
      JOIN (SELECT refid, MAX(datetime) max_datetime FROM (SELECT * FROM t3 UNION SELECT * FROM t4) t GROUP BY t.refid) t_comments2
        ON t_comments1.refid = t_comments2.refid AND t_comments1.datetime = t_comments2.max_datetime
  ) t_comments
  ON t1.id = t_comments.refid;
```